# how not to hard code connection stringin all pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2005

I have a webconfig file which has a connectionstring in it...

But then when ever i access  a database i have to write the same connectionstring again and again... is there a way it can take the value of the connectionstring from the webconfig file itself..????

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection dataConnection = new SqlConnection();
            dataConnection.ConnectionString =
                @"Data Source=JAGMIT-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SumooHAgentDB;Integrated Security=True";

            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand dataCommand = new SqlCommand();
            dataCommand.Connection = dataConnection;
```

any suggestions??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
string strConnString = 
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NameOfConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

EDIT:
Your code would now look something like this:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection dataConnection = new SqlConnection();
            dataConnection.ConnectionString =
                ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NameOfConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand dataCommand = new SqlCommand();
            dataCommand.Connection = dataConnection;
```

Just remember to replace NameOfConnectionString with the actual name of your connection string, and add a reference to System.Configuration (thanks NissanFan!)

Comment: Make sure you add a reference to System.Configuration before you do this.

Comment: And make sure to place your updated (since its not used, can be outdated) connection string inside /configuration/connectionStrings hive, in your web.config

Comment: so in this im hard coding Data Source=JAGMIT-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SumooHAgentDB;Integrated Security=True in place of NameofConnectionstring???

Comment: so whats the difference between what i wrote in my code and what u have written... by doing this i still am writing the entireconnectionstring on each page,,,,

Comment: No, the webconfig gets a line in the connectionstrings section associating "NameOfConnectionString" to "Data Source=JAGMIT-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SumooHAgentDB;Integrated Security=True" so that you don't have the hardcoded value all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

**How to: Read Connection Strings from the Web.config File**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178411.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In .NET there is a standard object named My.Settings that automatically refers to all your settings in the webconfig file.

You refer to values there as `My.Settings.Item("settingName")`